# How to pass Parcelable to two or more Activities or Fragments?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, parcelable

I can pass `Parcelable` to one Fragment or Activities but I can't pass `Parcelable` to two or more Fragment or Activities.

I have a ListView in Fragment when i click list item, list item details will be send to GetFragment1, GetFragment1 I have button to show more details of list item, I want to get Parcelable from SendFragment in GetFragment2 and GetFragment3.

This is Test.java

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Test implements Parcelable {

    private int studentNumber;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentFamily;

    public int getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentFamily() {
        return studentFamily;
    }

    public void setStudentFamily(String studentFamily) {
        this.studentFamily = studentFamily;
    }

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(Parcel read) {
        studentNumber = read.readInt();
        studentName = read.readString();
        studentFamily = read.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel write, int flags) {
        write.writeInt(studentNumber);
        write.writeString(studentName);
        write.writeString(studentFamily);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Test> CREATOR =
            new Parcelable.Creator<Test>() {
                @Override
                public Test createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                    return new TestP(source);
                }
                @Override
                public Test[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new TestP[size];
                }
            };
}
```

In `FragmentSend.java` I want to send data to `FragmentGet1.java` and `FragmentGet2.java` and `FragmentGet3.java`, this is the code:

```
public class FragmentSend extends ListFragment {

    //    Classes
    TestReadData readData;
    TestDataSource dataSource;

    private List<Test> listTest;       

    public FragmentSend() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);

        readData = new TestReadData(getContext());
        dataSource = new TestDataSource(getContext());  

       refreshStudentList(inflater);

    return layout;
}

public void refreshStudentList(LayoutInflater inflater) {

    listTest = readData.getAllStudentRows();
    ArrayAdapter<Test> testAdapter = new TestFragmentListAdapter(inflater.getContext(), listTest);
    setListAdapter(testAdapter);

}

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dataSource.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        dataSource.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Test model = listTest.get(position);

         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putParcelable("Student", model);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    Fragment fragmentGet1 = new FragmentGet1();
    Fragment fragmentGet2 = new FragmentGet2();
    Fragment fragmentGet2 = new FragmentGet3();

    fragmentGet1.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentGet2.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentGet3.setArguments(bundle);



    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragmentGet1);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

in `GetFragment1.java` I can get `Parclable` successfully but in two other Fragments (`GetFragment2.java` and `GetFragment3.java`) the bundle will be null!

This is GetFragment1.java code for getting Parcelable:
I use this code for other two Fragments.

```
Bundle bundle;
bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
                model = bundle.getParcelable("Student");
                if (model != null) {

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(String.valueOf(model.getStudentNumber());

                }
            } else {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "LogDetailsFragment 'bundle' is null!");
            }
```

how can i send `Parcelable` for more Fragments?

Comment: Are you actually adding the other two fragments into the transaction, with .replace(), .add() or some other method?

Comment: @Kelevandos no, should I do this?

Comment: Well, yes, only then will the fragment get created and be able to receive its arguments :-) You do this for Fragment1 and that is why it does receive the Bundle just fine

Comment: @Kelevandos but I don't want to show GetFragment2 or GerFragment3, I just want to show GetFragment1 and pass Parcelable to all of theme, is there any way to do that?

Comment: So what do you need them for? Maybe some other class would do better? Please elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve :-)

Comment: @Kelevandos question Edited.

Comment: But why do you want to pass it to other fragments if you do not want to show these fragments at all?

Comment: @Kelevandos I just want to get studentNumber and show all details of this student, in GetFragment1 student details is Name And Family but In GetFragment2 and 3 student details is everything.

Comment: And do I understand correctly that the Fragments will be chained? The FragmentSend will open only FragmentGet1, FragmentGet1 will open FragmentGet2 and FragmentGet2 will open FragmentGet3?

Comment: @Kelevandos yes, that's right :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your problem is in the sequence of things. In this part of your code:

```
Fragment fragmentGet1 = new FragmentGet1();
Fragment fragmentGet2 = new FragmentGet2();
Fragment fragmentGet2 = new FragmentGet3();

fragmentGet1.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentGet2.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentGet3.setArguments(bundle);
```

You are creating **instances** of all the 3 fragments, but then only using the instance of FragmentGet1. The other ones are not used. Later, when you create another instance of any of those Fragments, it will not have the args because *it is a totally separate object*.

That you need is to pass the bundle forward each time you create a new Fragment. If you want to create it from within an already-created fragment, it will look somewhat like this:

```
public void showNextFragment() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragmentGet2 = new FragmentGet2();

    if(this.getArguments() != null)
        fragmentGet2.setArguments(this.getArguments());

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragmentGet2);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Put it into your FragmentGet1 and let me know if this if what you need :-)

EDIT:
To pass the Student object to an Activity, just do something like this:

```
    Student s = //get it here
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("student", s);

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ThatOtherActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("extraWithStudent", b);
    startActivity(i);
```

And then to read the data in the Activity:

```
    Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = incomingIntent.getBundleExtra("extraWithStudent");
    Student s = (Student) b.getParcelable("student");
```

Comment: FragmentGet1 open an TabsActivity with two tabs: FragmentGet2 and FragmentGet3, should I pass bundle to TabsActivity first then pass it to two fragments?

Comment: Yeah, just pass it to the activity and then to the Fragments when you create the instances you will add().

Comment: can u tell me how to send Parcelable from fragment to activity?

Comment: Put it inside the intent you are using to start the activity, using the .putExtra(String, Bundle) method :-) Then, in Activity, use getIntent().getExtra(String) to read it.

Comment: I get this error:
'android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to com.saly.student'
would u please write the currect code. @KKelevandos